# How can I match a regexp containing newlines?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, variables, matchadd

When developing a vim plugin I'll publish soon, I want to highlight a text contained in a variable `g:last_completion_text`.

Here below the code to

- define an highlight group named `PrompterCompletion`
- assign the highlight to a text in a global vim variable `g:last_completion_text`

```
:highlight PrompterCompletion  ctermbg=3  ctermfg=0
:execute 'match PrompterCompletion /' . g:last_completion_text . '/'
```

If `g:last_completion_text` is a single line the code works correctly.

```
echo g:last_completion_text
Hello! How can I assist you today?
```

[image: variable is a single line]

But if `g:last_completion_text` is a multiline text (contains newline), the match command fails.

```
echo g:last_completion_text
21. Regione dell'enogastronomia
22. Regione della neve
23. Regione delle malghe
24. Regione delle tradizioni contadine
25. Regione delle fiabe e delle leggende
26. Regione della natura incontaminata
27. Regione delle attività all'aria aperta
28. Regione dell'architettura alpina
29. Regione delle terme e del benessere
30. Regione della storia e della cultura tirolesi.
```

[image: variable is a multiline]

**Screenshots**

```
echo g:last_completion_text
```

[image: echo]

```
echom g:last_completion_text
```

[image: echom]

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way to let the match command accept newlines in the text contained in the referenced variable?

Is there a way to correct the command:

```
:execute 'match PrompterCompletion /' . g:last_completion_text . '/'
```

Comment: For the record: if this is for a plugin, see the end of `:help :match`. That command is mostly for users now; plugins should use `matchadd()` or text properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
:execute 'match PrompterCompletion /' . substitute(g:last_completion_text, "[\n\<C-m>]", '\\n', 'g') . '/'
```

Comment: Could you give the result of the following call: `:echom g.last_completion_text`?

Comment: I suspect that there are other special characters to substitute ;-)

Comment: :echom g:last_completion_text

21. Regione delle malghe^@22. Regione delle cime^@23. Regione delle valli^@24. Regione dei laghi alpini^@25. Regione del Sud delle Alpi^@26. Regione del confine italo-austriaco^@27. Regione dei sapori alpini^@28. Regione della neve e dello sci^@29. Regione delle tradizioni contadine^@30. Regione dei parchi naturali

Comment: so the multiline text seems containing ^@ ?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the solution to include that null character too (and to make the substitution global) :-)

Comment: Great! It works perfectly if I run the updated command from command line.
I become crazy escaping in python .... 
 vim.command("execute 'match PrompterCompletion /' . substitute(g:last_completion_text, \"[\\n\\<C-m>]\", '\\\\n', 'g') . '/' ")

Anyway it now it works! Upvoted/thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: minor advertising :-) I just published the alfa version of the mentioned plugin: https://github.com/solyarisoftware/prompter.vim/

Comment: https://github.com/solyarisoftware/prompter.vim#-acknowledgements

Comment: Thanks for the Acknowledgment ;-) My contribution is very very minor :-)